# getopts is not recognizing the specified options as valid

Tags: bash, shell, getopts

I wrote the following shellscript. I am trying to get inputs from the user using the getopts method. This is the getopts fragment of code that I wrote.

```
#Define the help function
function help(){
    echo "Options:";
    echo "-u    Github username"
    echo "-p    Github password"
    echo "-r    Repository name"
    echo "-s    Service name"
    echo "-b    Branch name (Default master)"
    exit 1;
}


#Initialize the default values for the variables.
username="username";
password="password";
rname="rname";
sname="sname";
branch="master";

#Define the getopts variables
options="u:p:r:s:h";

#Start the getopts code
while getopts options opt; do
    case $opt in
            u) #Get the username
                    username=$OPTARG
            ;;
            p) #Get the password
                    password=$OPTARG
            ;;
            r) #Get the repository name
                    rname=$OPTARG
            ;;
            s) #Get the service name
                    sname=$OPTARG
            ;;
            b) #Get the branch name
                    branch=$OPTARG
            ;;
            h) #Execute the help function
        "echo here"
                    help;
            ;;
            \?) #unrecognized option - show help
                    echo "Invalid option."
                    help;
            ;;
    esac
done

#This tells getopts to move on to the next argument.
shift $((OPTIND-1))
#End getopts code
```

I tried to start the script by:

```
./testScript.sh -u myname
```

I get the following error:

```
illegal option -- u
```

Answer (score 4):

```
while getopts "$options" opt
#             ^^       ^
```

`$` substitutes in the value of the variable `options`.  Without the `$`, `getopts` thinks the valid flags are -o, -p, -t, -i, -n, and -s.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the dollar sign in front of options to consider it a variable:

```
 #Start the getopts code
 while getopts $options opt; do
```

Al